# How to output a grid field within a relationship?

Tags: relationships, grid, related-entries

I was wondering how I output the contents of a grid field from within a relationship. I've got two related entries and everything is showing correctly except the grid (which contains an image and text field).

I have tried a number of variations but haven't been successful yet

```
{relationship}
...
  {relationship:grid_field}
    {relationship:grid_field:image}
    {relationship:grid_field:text}
  {/relationship:grid_field}
{/relationship}

{relationship}
...
  {relationship:grid_field}
    {grid_field:image}
    {grid_field:text}
  {/relationship:grid_field}
{/relationship}

{relationship}
...
  {relationship:grid_field}
    {relationship:image}
    {relationship:text}
  {/relationship:grid_field}
{/relationship}

{relationship}
...
  {grid_field:relationship}
    {grid_field:relationship:image}
    {grid_field:relationship:text}
  {/grid_field:relationship}
{/relationship}
```

etc. Does anyone know the correct way to do this? The three dots represent the other content / fields. The way I have been outputting the other fields is as so: `{relationship:field_name}` and that has been working fine.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

**edit**

```
  {embed='includes/header'}
  {exp:channel:entries channel="project" status="not Closed"}
  <div class="col-100 content-area">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <main class="col-sm-8 col-md-8">
          <h2>{title}</h2>
          <div class="flexslider">
            <ul class="slides">
              {project_image}
              <li data-thumb="{exp:ce_img:single src='{project_image:image}' height='102' width='170' crop='yes' url_only='yes' allow_scale_large='yes'}">
                {exp:ce_img:single src="{project_image:image}" height="330" width="555" crop="yes" attributes='alt="{project_image:alt_tag}"'}
              </li>
              {/project_image}
            </ul>
          </div>
          {project_content}
        </main>
        <aside class="col-sm-4 col-md-offset-1 col-md-3 sidebar">
          <h3>Project Overview</h3>
          <div class="project-overview">
            {if client != ""}<p><strong>Client:</strong> {client}</p>{/if}
            {if project_cost != ""}<p><strong>Project cost:</strong> {project_cost}</p>{/if}
            {if location != ""}<p><strong>Location:</strong> {project_location}</p>{/if}
            {features}
            {if features:feature != ""}
            {if features:count == 1}
            <p><strong>Features:</strong></p>
            <ul class="project-features">
              {/if}
              <li>{features:feature}</li>
              {if features:count == features:total_rows}
            </ul>
            {/if}
            {/if}
            {/features}
            <p><strong>Sectors:</strong> {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" group_id="1" style="linear"}<a href="{path='sectors'}/{cat_url_title}">{cat_name}</a>{if cat_count != results}, {/if}{/exp:gwcode_categories}</p>
            <p><strong>Services:</strong> {exp:gwcode_categories entry_id="{entry_id}" group_id="2" style="linear"}<a href="{path='services'}/{cat_url_title}">{cat_name}</a>{if cat_count != results}, {/if}{/exp:gwcode_categories}</p>
          </div>
          {testimonial}
          {if testimonial:quote != ""}
          <blockquote>
            <h3>"{exp:excerpt}{testimonial:quote}{/exp:excerpt}"</h3>
            <p>- {testimonial:quotee}</p>
          </blockquote>
          {/if}
          {/testimonial}
        </aside>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-100 project-col">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
          <h2>Related Projects</h2><a href="{path='projects'}" class="more-link"> View all</a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row project-row">
        {projects_related status="not Closed" limit="2"}
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <h3>{projects_related:title}</h3>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
              {projects_related:project_image limit="1"}
              {exp:ce_img:single src="{projects_related:project_image:image}" height="199" width="360" crop="yes" attributes='alt="{projects_related:project_image:alt_tag}"'}
              {/projects_related:project_image}
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
              <p><strong>Location:</strong> {projects_related:project_location}</p>
              <p><strong>Brief details:</strong> {projects_related:project_brief}</p>
              <a href="{path='projects'}/{projects_related:url_title}" class="more-link">Find out more</a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        {/projects_related}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  {/exp:channel:entries}
  {embed='includes/footer'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works in my tests when accessing a child relationship:

```
{relationship_field}

    <p>Child entry title: {relationship_field:title}</p>

    {relationship_field:grid_field}
        Column 1: {relationship_field:grid_field:grid_column_1} <br>
        Column 2: {relationship_field:grid_field:grid_column_2} <br>
        {!--   etc...   --}
    {/relationship_field:grid_field}

{/relationship_field}
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I've tried the above but haven't been successful. I've just added the full template file to the question. Maybe I've misinterpreted your answer, or indeed the relationship field. 
Thank you.

Comment: This helped me get to where I wanted in the end, however the error was on my part. I feel foolish for saying this but I hadn't even uploaded an image...

Comment: Those are the hardest errors to track down for me! Glad you got it going.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to throw in my solution here because overall I find it much simpler.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="relationship_channel" dynamic="no"}

  {relationship_field}

    {relationship_field:title} // the title of our channel entry which has the grid

    {relationship_field:grid_field} // starts our loop inside of the grid

      {grid_field:grid_field_label} // we don't need to specify that we're in the relationship anymore, just that we're in the grid.

    {/relationship_field:grid_field}

  {/relationship_field}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Hope this is helpful to someone.